# PHP - How to unlink a file with no file extention

Tags: php, file, file-permissions, unlink

This work great to delete php, txt and images but I recently starting using an image resize that inserts temp images in to my trash folder.

*** example name 2616cf442b6cd3e1313161551fad6078 ***

File type: text/x-generic

Permission:  0644

Tried renaming to .txt with no luck

```
$cleantrash =(DOCROOT."/woobe/myfiles/trash/"); 
$cleantrash = opendir($cleantrash);

while (($filex_clean = readdir($cleantrash)) !== false) {
if($filex_clean != "." && $filex_clean != ".." && $filex_clean != "index.php") {


        echo "<b>Cleaing Trash...</b> $filex_clean<br>";
        unlink($filex_clean);
        }
}
closedir($cleantrash);
```

***EDIT  ***

```
$newname = basename($filename, ".bmp").".jpg";
rename($filename, $newname);
```

and the files are gone lol. No unlink useds? so where did they go?

Comment: What are the permissions on that file? Also, is it owned by the same user that your PHP is running as?

Comment: File permission is 0644 and yes

Comment: why would you rename a file just to delete it.  unlink works with any filename, but the path needs to be used, or the current working directory needs to be set to the same one that the file is in.

Comment: Yeah, thats what Ive read but everything deletes fine except the files with no extensions as I said above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The readdir() function returns file names without their paths (relative to the resource directory parameter you pass it).

The unlink() function expects the full file path.  My guess would be that you need to save the $cleantrash path instead of overwriting it with the resource from opendir(), and then do something like:

```
unlink($cleantrash . $filex_clean);
```

Comment: as I said, everything deletes except the files with no extensions so its not a path issue